# Why is Spring Boot 3 WAR not running in Tomcat 10 or 11?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I have recently updated my Spring Boot application to Spring Boot 3. However, when I try to run it on Tomcat 10 or Tomcat 11, nothing happens. There is nothing in the logs - no error. Opening the app locally returns 404. I can see the deployment running when I go to /manager/html.

I am attaching my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openhtmltopdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openhtmltopdf-pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.2.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.18.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>42.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.CR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-collections</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.laurell.log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>extended-jsonlayout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.157</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.0</version>
                        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is it possible to run Spring Boot 3 on Tomcat? Am I missing some package?

Does the Spring Tomcat dependency support Tomcat 10/11?

Thank you for help and appreciate any tip!

Comment: The url May be different than you think.

Answer (score 1):

Very Small Spring Boot 3.x WAR Examples

## hello project

```
hello
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── DemoSpringbootJspApplication.java
        │           └── HelloJSPController.java
        ├── resources
        │   └── application.properties
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── jsp
                    └── hello.jsp
```

### application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

### DemoSpringbootJspApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSpringbootJspApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoSpringbootJspApplication.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSpringbootJspApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### HelloJSPController.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class HelloJSPController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hellojsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(Map<String, Object> model) {
    
        System.out.println("HelloJSP Controller hello");
        
        model.put("message", "HelloJSP Controller hello");

        // /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
        return new ModelAndView("hello");
    }
}
```

### index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<%
// debug
System.out.println("webapp / index.jsp ");
%>
<body>
   <h1 class="color-red">SpringBoot index.jsp!!  <%="HELLO WORLD"%> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<%
// debug
System.out.println("webapp / WEB-INF / jsp / hello.jsp ");
%>
<body>
   <h1 class="color-red">SpringBoot hello.jsp!!  ${message} </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-springboot-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-springboot-jsp</name>
    <description>Demo Spring Boot JSP</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <finalName>hello</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## Package

run `mvn clean package`

## Put tomcat 10

copy target/hello.war to your tomcat 10 /webapps/

cd tomcat 10 /bin/

run `./startup.sh`

## web test

`http://localhost:8080/hello/` <-- index.jsp

`http://localhost:8080/hello/hellojsp` <-- HelloJSPController and hello.jsp

## check log file

tomcat 10 `/logs/catalina.out`

```
...
during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.4)

2023-03-31T14:48:47.067+08:00  INFO 20122 --- [           main] c.example.DemoSpringbootJspApplication   : Starting DemoSpringbootJspApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
...
31-Mar-2023 14:48:48.354 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [2802] milliseconds
webapp / index.jsp 
2023-03-31T14:49:17.896+08:00  INFO 20122 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-31T14:49:17.897+08:00  INFO 20122 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
HelloJSP Controller hello
webapp / WEB-INF / jsp / hello.jsp 
HelloJSP Controller hello
webapp / WEB-INF / jsp / hello.jsp
```

you can find spring boot war file startup and jsp output message to log.

## Environment

- apache-tomcat-10.1.5
- JDK : OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10)
- maven: Apache Maven 3.8.4

Comment: Sure, that seems fine, but when I add the dependencies in my pom.xml, then Tomcat does not start a WAR. Is there a way to see some error message why Tomcat does not start it?

Comment: First of all, we need to rule out environmental problems, so, can you copy my file and generate war, and then execute it successfully on your tomcat 10? If so, your environment should be fine.

Comment: start tomcat , then check , tomcat `/logs/`, (1) catalina.2023-04-03.log (2) catalina.out (3) localhost.2023-04-03.log (4) localhost_access_log.2023-04-03.txt, check any error message in log files.

Comment: Which URL does your `/manager/html` refer to? `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` or `http://localhost:8080/yourapp/manager/html`